# Unable to load the requested file: validation.php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am new to developing, and I want to do a simple validation in Codeigniter. I don't know where I am going wrong.
This is my form to be validated[image]

And my controller is this

```
public function __construct()
{   
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('M_menu');
    $this->load->model('master/M_user_type');
    $this->load->helper(array('form'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
public function index()
{
    $data['menus']=$this->M_menu->getSideBarMenu_m();$data['error_message'] = '';
    $this->load->view('master/V_user_type',$data);
}
function saveUserType_c()
{
    $data['error_message'] = '';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userType', 'UserTypeName', 'required');
    echo var_dump($this->form_validation->run());
    if (!$this->form_validation->run() )
    {$data['menus']=$this->M_menu->getSideBarMenu_m();
    $data['error_message'] .= validation_errors();
    $this->load->view('master/V_user_type',$data);
    }
    else
    {
    $insert=$this->M_user_type->saveUserType_m();
    if($insert){
        $response=array("insert"=>true);
    }else{
        $response=array("insert"=>false);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

With this I get the network error, and data is being saved to db. But no action in form(form not loading). Please guide me, where I go wrong. Also, if I need to give any more details

Answer (score 0):

Please check your usertype view page, you can also load usertype view page before validation, so that you will be confirmed that usertype view page exist, I hope you understand my point.

Comment: I have tried this before validation. I am not sure, if we both mean the same...

Answer (score 0):

You have to load a model before you call its methods. Use this:

```
$this->load->model('M_user_type');
$insert=$this->M_user_type->saveUserType_m();
```